# How to use an enum type in powershell when configuring IIS using the powershell snapin

Tags: iis-7, powershell

I am using the IIS Powershell snapin to configure a new web application from scratch. I am new to PS. The following script will not workl as PS is not recognising the ManagedPipelineMode enum. If I change the value to 0 it will work. How can I get PS to understand th enum. I tried the Add-Type cmdlet and also load the Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly without any scuccess, these lines are now commented.

How can I get this PS script working with the enum ?

```
#Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Web.Administration
#[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
Import-Module WebAdministration

$AppPoolName = 'Test AppPool'

if ((Test-Path IIS:\apppools\$AppPoolName) -eq $false) {
    Write-Output 'Creating new app pool ...'
    New-WebAppPool -Name $AppPoolName
    $AppPool = Get-ChildItem iis:\apppools | where { $_.Name -eq $AppPoolName}
    $AppPool.Stop()
    $AppPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value "v4.0"
    $AppPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode]::Integrated
    $AppPool.Start()

}
```

The error message is:

> Set-ItemProperty : [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode]::Integrated is not a valid value for Int32.

Comment: Whether AppPool.Stop and Apppool.Start are necessary always? I am creating Webapppool creation now. So I would like to know the significance of it

Comment: Any final solution with FULL source code sample working about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is expecting an integer, even though the underlying property is of type `ManagaedPipelineMode`. You can do below however:

```
$AppPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value ([int] [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode]::Classic)
```

PS:

Instead of

```
$AppPool = Get-ChildItem iis:\apppools | where { $_.Name -eq $AppPoolName}
```

you can do:

```
$AppPool = Get-Item iis:\apppools\$AppPoolName
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the error. Is there a way to not type the namespace "Microsoft.Web.Administration" everywhere ?

Comment: @Pratik - You might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048954/equivalent-to-cs-using-keyword-in-powershell

Comment: blurgh.. this should work but is convoluted. see my answer ;)

Comment: @x0n - Response in your answer. Please try out answers before giving them. I agree the answer is convoluted, but you should give a working answer.

Comment: In IIS 8.5 (Win2012), $appPool | set-itemproperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value $managedPipelineMode works, but not working in IIS 7.5 (Win2008)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding: `Add-Type -AssemblyName` - this will only work for a canned set of assemblies that PowwerShell knows about. You have to find the assembly in your file system and use the `-Path` parameter.  This worked on my system in a 64-bit PowerShell console:

```
Add-Type -Path C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll
```

Comment: This response was only in addressing the issue with Add-Type.  Also your path to the dll may be different especially if you're executing this in a x86 console.

Comment: @Keith Hill: As this dll is available in GAC, Is there any way to get it from there instead of providing full path? I am writting powershell script which will be placed in production environment, If i use hard coded full path it may end up in error.

Comment: @Keith Hill: I have written like this and it works. $Loc= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration") 
    Add-Type -Path $Loc.Location

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
$AppPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" `
   -Value [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode]::Integrated
```

use:

```
$AppPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" `
   -Value ([Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode]::Integrated)
```

or the even more succinct:

```
$AppPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value Integrated
```

Why? The reason you need brackets in the first answer is because the parameter binder is treating the entire `[Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode]::Integrated` in your attempt as a string, which cannot be cast to that enumerated type. However, `Integrated` can be to that enum. By wrapping it in brackets, it is evaluated again as an expression and is treated as a full type literal.

Comment: Did you try that? `$AppPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" `
   -Value ([Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode]::Integrated)
` will give `Integrated is not a valid value for Int32`.

Comment: @manojlds oh, right, -value is not typed to the enum. I was blind to the fact it was set-itemproperty. if -value was of that enum type, the string shortcut would work. oops.

Comment: In IIS 8.5 (Win2012), $appPool | set-itemproperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value $managedPipelineMode works, but not working in IIS 7.5 (Win2008)