# How to simplify access to enum in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, enums, static

I would like to know whether it is possible to shorten this notation:

```
$someEnumValue = [Some.Long.Namespace.I.Have.To.Repeat.Several.Times]::ValueXY
$anotherEnumValue = [Some.Long.Namespace.I.Have.To.Repeat.Several.Times]::ValueXZ
```

to something like:

```
$allEnumValues = [Some.Long.Namespace.I.Have.To.Repeat.Several.Times]
$someEnumValue = $allEnumValues::ValueXY
$anotherEnumValue = $allEnumValues::ValueYZ
```

Comment: Very dupey: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1049010/3829407

Comment: Yeah, it is. I haven't found it because I was focused on enums and that one is not about it. Regardless, it turned out that I was just not so diligent when I was trying that. Should this be closed, or is it worth keeping?

Comment: Dupes are good. If you didnt find it and made this question chances are someone else will think the same way. In either case the right content will be made available. Good dupes are good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you listed will Work on the usual `System.Enum` objects:

```
PS H:\> [System.DayOfWeek].BaseType.FullName
System.Enum
PS H:\> [System.DayOfWeek]::Monday
Monday
PS H:\> [System.DayOfWeek]::Tuesday
Tuesday
PS H:\> $Week = [System.DayOfWeek]
PS H:\> $Week::Monday
Monday
PS H:\> $Week::Tuesday
Tuesday
```

If you're using a custom enum format please post the code you're using to create it in the first place.

Comment: Ok, so I must have been trying that in a wrong/different way. It really works now just as I wanted to. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   public enum allEnumValues
   {
      Some,
      Long,
      Namespace,
      I,
      Have,
      To,
      Repeat,
      Several,
      Times
   }
"@


$someEnumValue = [allEnumValues]::ValueXY
$anotherEnumValue = [allEnumValues]::ValueYZ
```